# add external process to panel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a list of files displayed in a listbox.
when I select a file from the listbox i want the file to load into a panel on my form.
i.e. if its a word document word will open in the panel, if its a pdf reader wil open into the panel.

I can get the files to load externally using

```
Dim ProcStart As New ProcessStartInfo
ProcStart.FileName = ListBox1.SelectedItem
Process.Start(ProcStart)
```

however i am unsure of how to get it to then dock in my panel. I tried

```
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(ProcStart)
```

but this is obviously wrong as I can't add a process as a control.

I did a bit of googleing and have tried to do it this way

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As UInteger
End Function
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim proc As Process
    Dim AppPath As String

    AppPath = lstDocs & ListBox1.SelectedItem
    proc = Process.Start(AppPath)
    proc.WaitForInputIdle()

    SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Me.Panel1.Handle)


End Sub
```

but the word application still opens outside my program and not in the panel!!

Any ideas? and thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a button with code behind it to start the process?

'This is how i would start the process

this would be in your code that starts the control ( inserting )

```
Dim dep1 As (INSERT YOUR EVENT HERE)= New (INSERT YOUR EVENT HERE)
AddHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange
```

the actuall button

```
Private Sub dep_onchange1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' this event is run asynchronously so you will need to invoke to run on the UI thread(if required)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        lbnoes.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf GetNoes))
    Else
        GetNoes()
    End If
 End Sub
```